# I get the same python version after installed and activated virtualenv with different python version

Tags: python, virtualenv

I want to use a different python version in a virtual environment. I usually create a new environment and set the python version I want. But now, in a new machine I'm working, it doesn't work. I install a venv with python3.5, activate it, but it still uses the default python3.6

```
virtualenv --python=python3.5 testenv
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python3.5
Using base prefix '/usr'
New python executable in /home/mwon/testenv/bin/python3.5
Also creating executable in /home/mwon/testenv/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
```

then

```
source testenv/bin/activate
```

result:

```
python
Python 3.6.5 (default, Mar 29 2018, 03:28:50) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

EDIT:

Distro:

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="16.04.3 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
```

Python version:

```
Python 3.6.5
```

Comment: What system (OS, distro, etc.) is this? Can you post the full log of `virtualenv --python=python3.5 newtestenv; source newtestenv/bin/activate; python --version; which python`?

Comment: 16.04.3 LTS (Xenial Xerus). How to I get the full log of virtualenv? The default python version if the 3.6.5

Comment: I mean, just copy-paste the terminal output as-is into a code block.

Comment: The terminal output is the one I show in the main question. The same for the other commands. Just updated the distrib.

Comment: Do you have `python` defined as an alias?  Check the output of `type python`.

Comment: Ok, I think so. It results in `python is aliased to 'python3.6'`. But I have the same result in another machine where everything works fine.

Comment: Sorry, forget the last answer. That might be the problem. How do I remove it?

Comment: Ok, did it with `unalias`. It's working now. Thanks!